# Weird dots left on TextArea

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am currently trying to learn Javafx and i am having problems with modifying a Textarea with css. THe picture below shows best what the problem is:
[image]

I designed it with Scene Builder. Below is the CSS code for the text area:

```
.text-area .content{
    -fx-background-color: #2d2d2d;
    -fx-text-fill: white; 

}

.text-area{
    -fx-background-color: #2d2d2d;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.text-area:focus .content{
    -fx-background-color: #2d2d2d;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

I have tried commenting stuff out, but the white dots remain. So my Question is how to fix this.

Comment: It looks like there is a white background behind everything, and somewhere there is a `-fx-background-radius` set, so you are just seeing behind your background at the corners. (I think I've seen this before, no time to search now.) Try setting `-fx-background-radius: 0;`. Will test later if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Thank you sooo much. that was it. I added it to all the 3 css classes and it fixed the problem.